# Formally prove convolution with Dirac Delta returns the same function?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

Let $\delta$ be the Dirac Delta distribution and $f$ be Riemann-integrable. Then it is said $(f*\delta)(t) = f(t).$

But, I'm wondering if this can be proven. The dirac delta distribution converges to an object that's $0$ everywhere except at $y = 0.$

So this leave us with a question, what is the value of the integral at 0? We evaluate $\lim_{R \rightarrow 0} \int_{-R}^{R}f(t,y)\delta(y)dy$ which is

$$ \lim_{R \rightarrow 0} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}f(t,y_i)\delta(y_i)\Delta y,$$ but I'm unsure what to do from here or where to find a reference.

Comment: The Dirac delta isn't a function, so writing $\delta(y_i)$ doesn't make sense.  The statement $(f*\delta)(t) = f(t)$ is the _definition_ of $\delta$, so it's not something that can be proven.  It's kind of like how the fact that $1\cdot x = x$ for all $x$ can't be proven, but is rather the mathematical definition of $1$.

Comment: You need to look at distributions to see how these things are formalised. It is convenient that treating the $\delta$ distribution as a magic functions works so well in practice.

Comment: Answerers: You can check out [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4520711/how-did-this-poster-derive-2-for-convolutions) to see what others have tried before hoping to explain the delta distribution.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC oh... good to know. Hey, askquestions2: The answer to this question is really that the answer to your question stated in a comment there: *How does the integral simplify in such a way that it's equivalent to taking f(τ) at τ=0?* is: **That** exactly is the definition of the Delta Dirac distribution. It's a mathematical model for a "thing" that evaluates a function at a specific point when being used as integration kernel. All your confusion seems to stem from the fact that you "refuse" to accept "it's the definition" as explanation.But it's really just the definition!

Comment: Now, a lot of the work that "flowed" into what the Dirac Delta distribution is is showing that *a lot* of the things you can do with it make it look as if it was a function in most cases. It's not. Especially, the integral over it does *not* converge to a Riemann sum.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I'm only now connecting the dots that the asker is the [same as in this question on the signal processing site](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/84356/what-are-applications-of-time-shifted-convolution-with-dirac-delta?noredirect=1#comment178119_84356) and now I'm a bit concerned on whether my answer will be well-received.

Answer (score 1):

> But, I'm wondering if this can be proven.

It's the very definition of the Delta Dirac distribution that integrating a product with it yields the original function evaluated at the integration variable at 0.

Plug that into the definition of convolution, and your statement literally is written there.

Your limiting approach to integration will not take you further – since  that is Riemann integration, and only bounded functions can be Riemann integrated. The Delta Dirac distribution is neither a function nor bounded.
Luckily, that's not a problem, since this is really just a matter of applying the definition of the Delta Dirac distribution with the integral.

Comment: I don't know that your statement is correct. It's not the definition, it's a property that results from its definition, thus requiring proof. There's enormous technical work you're neglecting in approximation theory to show that there even exists a sequence that can approximate the identity distribution in the first place.

Comment: OK, do you have the definition for me then? You seem to be assuming a different definition than what is taught, and written down in several places, including wikipedia, as the measure-theoretic definition. Please link to a definition or add it explicitly to your question!

Answer (score 0):

If $f \in C_{c}^{\infty}$, then by definition of distributional convolution,
$$(\delta * f)(x) = \langle \delta(y), f(x - y) \rangle_y = f(x).$$
The above doesn't work for an arbitrary Riemann integrable $f$, as the definition of $\delta * f$ is different in this case. For such $f$ you can use the density of $C_c^{\infty}$ in the space of distributions to get a sequence of $C_c^{\infty}$ functions converging in the topology of the space of distributions to $f$ to get the result. Alternatively, for such $f$ you can use the definition of convolution to easily show that $\delta * f = f$ in the sense of distributions (which here means that $\delta * f = f$ a.e.): For all $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}$,
$$\langle \delta * f, \phi \rangle = \langle f(y), \langle \delta(x), \phi(x + y) \rangle_{x} \rangle_{y} = \langle f(y), \phi(y) \rangle_{y} = \langle f, \phi \rangle.$$